# How to remove title from actionSheet in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiactionsheet

Just like the question asks, how do I remove the title from the action sheet below? I'm using iOS 14, don't want to upgrade to `SwiftUI` 3. There's no initializer for the actionSheet with a titleVisibility parameter or anything like that. I also tried 'nil' as you can see below, but it's not optional. Not sure how to make the title disappear.

```
@State var showOptions: Bool = false
Button(action: {
    showOptions = true
}, label: {

}).actionSheet(isPresented: $showOptions) {
ActionSheet(
    title: nil,
    buttons: [
        .cancel(),
        .default(Text("Red")) {
            print("x")
        },

        .default(Text("Green")) {
            print("y")
        },

        .default(Text("Blue")) {
            print("z")
        },
        ]
    )
}
```

Comment: What about simply: `title: Text("")`? There'll be some (small) blank space at the top of the sheet, but it doesn't look too bad.

Comment: @tromgy I'd prefer it to not be there at all

Comment: The title is required for `ActionSheet`. If you don't want to upgrade and use `confirmationDialog` then you should live with it or implement your own custom *action sheet* w/o title.

Answer (score 0):

[ConfirmationDialog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:)-9ibgk) can be used to show Action Sheet behaviour without title.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingOptions = false
    @State private var selection = "None"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(selection)
            Button("Confirm paint color") {
                showingOptions = true
            }
            .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showingOptions, titleVisibility: .automatic) {
                ForEach(["Red", "Green", "Blue"], id: \.self) { color in
                    Button(color) {
                        selection = color
                    }
                }
            }
        }.frame(width:300, height: 600)
    }
}
```

[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH0LI.png)

Comment: The OP asked for an iOS 14 solution. `ConfirmationDialog` is iOS 15+.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 14

You can pass empty **ActionSheet** **title** like `title: Text("")`

[image]

Comment: it shows a empty space at the top